# Is there a way to create a large number of columns quickly?

Tags: column, batch

I am about to create 84 choice fields for a timesheet solution I am creating in Sharepoint. Clearly I am procrastinating on this task and here I am.

Is there a trick I don't know about that might help with this process?

The columns will have same settings: Choice, Exempt/Non-Exempt, default to blank.

The names obviously will be different, but similar, for example:
Non-Exempt, Monday, Week 1
Non-Exempt, Tuesday, Week 1

I already created 84 number fields with similar function and I'm trying to be lazy!

Thanks for any help.

(PS I did a quick search and didn't come up with anything but obviously if there is something already here on this I'd love a link. Cheers!)

Comment: use powershell to create your columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Mike pointed out, PowerShell is a very good to option in order to achieve what you want.

One option, is having a .CSV file like this:

[image]

Once you have that structure with your data, you can run this PowerShell script to create the columns:

```
$SiteURL = Read-Host "Input Site URL:"
$CSVPath = Read-Host "Input path to CSV:"
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity $SiteURL
$csv = import-csv -Path $CSVPath
$web = $site.RootWeb

Foreach ($ID in $csv){
    $XML = 
        '<Field
            Type="' + $ID.Type + '"
            Name="' + $ID.Name + '"
            Description="' + $ID.Description + '"
            DisplayName="' + $ID.DisplayName + '"
            StaticName="' + $ID.StaticName + '"
            Group="' + $ID.Group + '"
            Hidden="' + $ID.Hidden + '"
            Required="' + $ID.Required + '"
            Sealed="' + $ID.Sealed + '"
            ShowInDisplayForm="' + $ID.ShowInDisplayForm + '"
            ShowInEditForm="' + $ID.ShowInEditForm + '"
            ShowInListSettings="' + $ID.ShowInListSettings + '"
            ShowInNewForm="' + $ID.ShowInNewForm + '">
        </Field>'

    write-host ""
    write-host $XML
    write-host ""
    $web.Fields.AddFieldAsXML($XML)
    write-host ""
}
```

Notice that this will only create the columns, if you need to relate some column with some Content Type, this script doesn't make that.

Source: [Bulk Creation of SharePoint Site Columns via Powershell](https://oddmodlin.wordpress.com/2017/05/10/bulk-creation-of-site-columns-via-powershell/)

In the case you want to create columns, content types and relate them, you have a very useful tutorial series where steps with code is explained.

1. [Bulk Creation of SharePoint Site Columns and Content Types with PowerShell: Part 1](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/bulk-creation-of-sharepoint-site-columns-and-content-types-with-powershell-part-1)
2. [Bulk Creation of SharePoint Site Columns and Content Types with PowerShell: Part 2](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/bulk-creation-of-sharepoint-site-columns-and-content-types-with-powershell-part-2)
3. [Bulk Creation of SharePoint Site Columns and Content Types with PowerShell: Part 3](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/bulk-creation-of-sharepoint-site-columns-and-content-types-with-powershell-part-3)

Comment: Wow. Thanks @sergio this is exactly the kind of super helpful answer I was hoping for. I have put off diving in to PowerShell but I can see that it is the way to go for the type of work I now find myself doing. Super great response and I'm sure I'm not the only one who will benefit!